# How to add reset button in the dialog in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to the scripting, but from what I have learned from this website, I have put together a check book balancesheet in google sheets.

I have a function "AddCheck" attached to the button on one of the cell. What it does is - opens a dialog box where I enter check details, like Date, Invoice number, amount and vendor's name. Then I click the submit button and Google sheets creates a row and adds those values.

My Question is how do I add a button next to the submit button that will allow me to add the New check details without leaving the dialog box. So that it will add the values to the cells and will clear the dialog box for another Entry.

This is my AddCheck function

```
    function AddCheck() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=A4+1');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Pending');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();


  fncOpenMyDialog()

};
```

This is my HTML dialog file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>

<label for="Date">Date :</label>

    <input type='date' name='Date' id="Date" required="required"/>
    <br>
<label for="Invoice">Invoice</label>
    <input type='text' name='Invoice' id="Invoice" required="required"/>

<label for="Amount">Amount</label>
    <input type='text' name='Amount' id="Amount" required="required"/>

<label for="Company">Company</label>
<select name="Class" id="vendor-selector" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">

  <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById("vendor-selector");
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = selectList[i][0];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getSelectList();
      }());
    </script>


</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction(this.parentNode)">
</form>
<p id="CompanyName"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(obj) {
var x = document.getElementById("vendor-selector").value;
document.getElementById("CompanyName").innerHTML = x;
google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close())
    .functionToRunOnFormSubmit(obj);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This Function calls the Dialog

```
function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  //Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CheckDetails')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(250);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Check Details');
};


function functionToRunOnFormSubmit(fromInputForm) {

Logger.log(fromInputForm);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheetByName("Checks").getRange(3,3).setValues([[fromInputForm.Class]]);
  ss.getSheetByName("Checks").getRange(3,2).setValues([[fromInputForm.Date]]);
  ss.getSheetByName("Checks").getRange(3,4).setValues([[fromInputForm.Invoice]]);
  ss.getSheetByName("Checks").getRange(3,6).setValues([[fromInputForm.Amount]]);
};
```

and this Function gets the List of vendors from Sheet2

```
function getSelectList() 
         {
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("141mlnxJBjepKxYCGXHFhz5IIEVnp6T2DDsb_uRgnZzY").getSheetByName('Sheet2');
          var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
          var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
          var data = myRange.getValues();
          Logger.log("Data = " + data); 
          return data;
         };


         function doGet() 
         {
         return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CheckDetails');
         }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement this "Submit & Continue" feature, you only need to change the front-end code so that:

1. There is a new button.
2. Upon clicking the new button, the same back-end (GAS) code gets executed.
3. The dialog does not get closed after the GAS code execution, but the input elements are reset.

#### Code modifications

1. Add an id to the form tag so that it may be easily selected.

   ```html
   <form id="CheckDetailsForm">
   ```
2. Create a "Submit & Continue" button in your HTML. Assign an id to it so that it may be easily selected.

   ```html
   <input type="submit" value="Submit and continue" id="SubmitAndContinueInput" />
   ```
3. Within the `script` tag, add an event listener to the newly created button.

   ```js
   document.getElementById("SubmitAndContinueInput").addEventListener("click", myFunctionContinue);
   ```
4. Add the handler function for the newly created button's `onclick` event. This function will be very similar as the one you are using but: It will use the [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to avoid the form being incorrectly sent and will clear the form data upon submission.

   ```js
   function clearForm() {
     document.getElementById('Date').value = "";
     document.getElementById('Invoice').value = "";
     document.getElementById('Amount').value = "";
   }

   function myFunctionContinue(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var obj = document.getElementById("CheckDetailsForm");
     var x = document.getElementById("vendor-selector").value;
     document.getElementById("CompanyName").innerHTML = x;
     google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(clearForm)
       .functionToRunOnFormSubmit(obj);
   }
   ```

#### Example dialog:

[image: Example Sheets dialog]

#### Edit

Handling "submit and continue" new rows:

1. Remove the row-insertion functionality from `AddCheck()`. We will handle this logic afterwards:

   ```js
   function AddCheck() {
     fncOpenMyDialog();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the `functionToRunOnFormSubmit()` function so that it handles the row-insertion logic. I have also cleaned up the code a little bit. It would look like the following:

   ```js
   function functionToRunOnFormSubmit(fromInputForm) {
     Logger.log(fromInputForm);

     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Checks");

     sheet.insertRowBefore(3);

     sheet.getRange("A3").setFormula("=A4+1");
     sheet.getRange("B3").setValue(fromInputForm.Date);
     sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(fromInputForm.Class);
     sheet.getRange("D3").setValue(fromInputForm.Invoice);

     sheet.getRange("F3").setValue(fromInputForm.Amount);
     sheet.getRange("G3").setValue("Pending");
   }
   ```

#### Full code

*CheckDetails.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="CheckDetailsForm">

<label for="Date">Date :</label>

    <input type='date' name='Date' id="Date" required="required"/>
    <br>
<label for="Invoice">Invoice</label>
    <input type='text' name='Invoice' id="Invoice" required="required"/>

<label for="Amount">Amount</label>
    <input type='text' name='Amount' id="Amount" required="required"/>

<label for="Company">Company</label>
<select name="Class" id="vendor-selector" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">

  <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById("vendor-selector");
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = selectList[i][0];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getSelectList();
      }());
    </script>

</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitInput" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit and continue" id="SubmitAndContinueInput" />

</form>

<p id="CompanyName"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("SubmitInput").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
document.getElementById("SubmitAndContinueInput").addEventListener("click", myFunctionContinue);

function clearForm() {
  document.getElementById('Date').value = "";
  document.getElementById('Invoice').value = "";
  document.getElementById('Amount').value = "";
}

function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = document.getElementById("CheckDetailsForm");
  var x = document.getElementById("vendor-selector").value;
  document.getElementById("CompanyName").innerHTML = x;
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.host.close())
    .functionToRunOnFormSubmit(obj);
}

function myFunctionContinue(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var obj = document.getElementById("CheckDetailsForm");
  var x = document.getElementById("vendor-selector").value;
  document.getElementById("CompanyName").innerHTML = x;
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(clearForm)
    .functionToRunOnFormSubmit(obj);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Code.gs*

```js
function AddCheck() {
  fncOpenMyDialog()
}

function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  //Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CheckDetails')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(250);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'Check Details');
}

function functionToRunOnFormSubmit(fromInputForm) {
  Logger.log(fromInputForm);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Checks");

  sheet.insertRowBefore(3);

  sheet.getRange("A3").setFormula("=A4+1");
  sheet.getRange("B3").setValue(fromInputForm.Date);
  sheet.getRange("C3").setValue(fromInputForm.Class);
  sheet.getRange("D3").setValue(fromInputForm.Invoice);

  sheet.getRange("F3").setValue(fromInputForm.Amount);
  sheet.getRange("G3").setValue("Pending");
}

function getSelectList() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("141mlnxJBjepKxYCGXHFhz5IIEVnp6T2DDsb_uRgnZzY").getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow);
  var data = myRange.getValues();
  Logger.log("Data = " + data); 
  return data;
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CheckDetails');
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for .Thank you, Learned a lot.

Comment: @HemangParikh No worries! :) Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case my answer was useful to you. Have a good day!

Comment: so, one problem is that it dose not create a new row after adding the data when I click SubmitAndContinue, Every time it just modifies the same row. I need it to add a row above 3rd row before adding the new data. I tried putting add row script after clear document but dosen't work.

Comment: so basically I need the AddCheck function to run again before putting in the new data, so it will add a row, set the formula for check number and other stuff.

Comment: Hey @HemangParikh I have updated my answer with code on how to fix this issue you are having. Kindly let me know if this works for you now. Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much for helping me through this, I'm noob at this, so I tried modifying the  functionToRunOnFormSubmit but don't know where to put it, I did after clearform, even inside the the Submit & Continue. but it's not working. I'm stil Learning.

Comment: @HemangParikh I have edited the answer including the whole final code. Let me know if that works for you now ;) Cheers

Comment: You sir are great, Cleaned up the other file, and code looking so short and sweet, was doing so much unnecessary coding. Works great, Major reps.